# Python Unknown error in HTTP implementation

Tags: python, queue, python-asyncio, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have a simple telegram bot that needs to write a number less than 10, and it will count you from this number to zero with a delay of one second.

I want to make a queue of requests.
If the bot is already counting numbers, reply to the person that he has been added to the queue, and perform tasks in the queue.

I did it, but when the bot tries to process the second or third request, it writes an error.

Code:

```py
import time, asyncio
from threading import Thread
from telegram import ForceReply, Update
from telegram.constants import ParseMode
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, ContextTypes, MessageHandler, filters

TOKEN = ""

queue = []

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_html("Send me a number and I'll count from it to zero")
 
async def echo(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    msg = update.message.text
    if msg.isdigit():
        msg = int(msg)
        if msg > 0:
            data = {'update': update, 'number': msg}
            queue.append(data)
            pos = len(queue)
            await update.message.reply_text(f"Please wait. you're {pos} in queue")
 
async def count_to_zero(num, update):
    for i in range(num, -1, -1):
            await update.message.reply_text(i)
            time.sleep(2)

def queue_handler() -> None:
    while True:
        if len(queue) > 0:
            update = queue[0]['update']
            num = queue[0]['number']
            asyncio.run(count_to_zero(num, update))
            del queue[0]

thread = Thread(target=queue_handler)
thread.start()

def main() -> None:
    # Create the Application and pass it your bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()
 
    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
 
    # on non command i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, echo))
 
    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error:

> Unknown error in HTTP implementation: Runtime Error('<asyncio.locks.Event object at 0x000002495210ECE0 [unset]> is bound to a different event loop')

I tried to do through
async io.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

but in this case, the bot itself did not start, or the queue_handler function did not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use methods of the `update` objects in a different thread (and therefor different event loop) than they were created in. I highly recommend not to mix threading and asyncio. I'm rather confident that your use case can be solved by native `asyncio` methods, or even with PTBs built-in [`JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---JobQueue).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telgeram-bot`.